# Maven - Add options to the war jvm

Tags: spring, maven, war

When I deploy my application with

```
mvn install
```

It creates a file app.war, according to the pom request.

I need to add an option for the jvm that is called when I execute that war.

The option is

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

Is there something I could add to the pom to do that?

Comment: Only if you execute it via Maven; all a WAR file is is an artifact. Allowing JVM settings from within an artifact would be a huge security risk. Provide a default value that can be overridden.

Comment: Actually I do it changing the **jre/lib/security/java.security** with that option, but i didn't feel like it was the best way to do that